# There are eight males and 12 females in a certain club. In how many ways can a committee of five be chosen if it is to consist-

Tags: combinatorics

There are eight males and 12 females in a certain club. In how many ways can a committee of five be chosen if it is to consist

Entirely of Males?

Entirely of Females?

2 males and 3 females?

Comment: You need to show what you have attempted so far.  Were you able to do the first case?

Answer (score 1):

If it should consist entirely males it will be $\binom85$ and in the same fashion $\binom{12}5$ for females.

And for the other part, see [this link](http://www.math.nyu.edu/~damron/Fall2008/homework/HW8_solutions.pdf).
Hope, this link helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with binomial coefficients.

$\binom{8}{5}$ and $\binom{12}{5}$.